# Need help in Passing values from Java to nsis script

Tags: java, nsis

I need to pass the values which I get at runtime from a java code to nsis script to restrict the installer creation for a certain number of time. Is it possible....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you are trying to enforce a licensing limitation (number of times installable) by changing the nsis installer for your application (e.g. binary patching)? Any such attempt can be easily circumvented (copying) so I would not even try it. The best practice to enforce licensing limitations is to state them explicitly in the license you sell and if any company violates it let lawyers handle it.

Comment: Thanks eznme, but I also need to pass the exe dynamically from my java code. I have to create an installer for that exe. Is it possible to find a tag of the nsis script and replace it.

Comment: Sorry for not checking back sooner, really busy. Sure you can do that: Create the NSIS-Script dynamically using java's FileWriter class and a bunch of String-concatenations, then executing the NSIS-compiler on your NSIS-script like this: Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("pathToYourNSISexe pathToYourNSISscript");

Comment: I used this code. It doesnt run. Doesnt show any error. The script doesnt run.Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
    try { 
     proc = rt.exec("C:\\Program Files\\NSIS\\makensis.exe  C:\\Users\\FSSD100\\Desktop\\JavaSamp final\\simple.nsi");     
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }